# Why does dividing two time.durations in Go result in another time.duration?

Tags: go

I don't understand what it means to divide a `time.Duration` in Go.

For example, this is super lovely:

```
d,_ := time.ParseDuration("4s")
fmt.Println(d/4)
```

print `1s`. Which is ace, because (naively) 4 seconds divided by 4 is 1 second.

It gets a little confusing though when we find out that the 4 in the denominator has to be a duration. So although:

```
d1 := time.Duration(4)
fmt.Println(d/d1)
```

also prints `1s`, we know that `d1` is actually `4ns` and I'm entirely unconvinced that 4 seconds divided by 4 nanoseconds is 1 second.

I'm confused because a duration divided by duration should be dimensionless (I think, right?), whereas a duration divided by a dimensionless number should have units of time.

And I know that type != unit, but I'm clearly misunderstanding something, or quite possibly a set of things. Any help to clear this up would be most appreciated!

Here is a go playground of the above examples. https://play.golang.org/p/Ny2_ENRlX6. And just for context, I'm trying to calculate the average time between events. I can fall back to using floats for seconds, but am trying to stay in `time.Duration` land.

Comment: This is a flaw in the design of `time.Duration`.

Comment: Don't ignore errors and don't use `ParseDuration` for initialize `time.Duration` values. Use `d := 4 * time.Second` instead.

Comment: @райтфо it's your understanding of types that is flawed. An added method wouldn't help (would it take/return float64, float32, int, int64??) and wouldn't look/read any better than a simple type conversion.

Comment: @DaveC You're wrong. Dividing a duration by another one should never result in a duration. It's mathematically incorrect.

Comment: Most languages deal with **types** and do *not* deal with **units** or dimensional analysis. The fact that a (e.g.) a speed divided by time yields a length is irrelevant to typed languages and only relevant to a math language that understands units. As I said, if you don't understand this then you don't understand basic typed languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is so because `time.Duration` is `int64`. See documentation of [time package](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration).

You make a division of 4000000000 (4s) by 4 (4ns) and you get 1000000000 (1s). You should look at the operations as they where integers not typed values. Type `Duration` make it look like a physical value but for division operation it is just a number.

Answer (score 6):

Mathematically, you're correct: dividing two time.Durations should result in a dimensionless quantity. But that's not how go's type system works. Any mathematical operation results in a value of the same type as the inputs. You'll have to explicitly cast the result of the division to an int64 to get an "untyped" quantity.

Answer (score 3):

There are no units attached to a `time.Duration`.  A `time.Duration` represents the physical concept of a duration (measured in seconds and having a unit) by providing a distinct type, namely the `time.Duration` type.  But technically it is just a `uint64`.

If you try to attach actual units to types you'll enter unit-hell: What would a (time.Duration * time.Duration)/acceleration.Radial * mass.MetricTon be? Undefined most probably.